# Need guidance back into programming

Tags: programming-languages

I used to be a programmer and unix sysadmin back in the 90's and early 00's.  I wrote business software mostly in BBX, which was non-compiled, procedural BASIC.  It was all text based when I started, and I only just got into GUI and OOP with ProvideX by the time I got out.  I did do some SQL work and understand basic database concepts.

I've continually dabbled since and tried to keep up by running my own Debian web server here at the house, doing little script programs here and there, and most recently learning PHP and Python.  But I would like to get versed in the current state of the industry and hopefully make myself employable in it again.

My current learning project is to write a db app that I can use when drag racing to log run data, report based on various combinations of variables, and predict vehicle performance.  This should cover IO, data management, and some complex math.  I do want to make is sellable, so it has to be in Windows since all other racing software is.  My two options now are to write it in MSAccess, which isn't really programming, or to write a front end in Python and use MySQL for the data.

I assume I should go the Python path out of those two, or should I choose a third path that would pay more dividends toward a job?  My biggest concern is wasting my time learning pointless stuff.  I assume most of the work out there is db related and web based applications, so that would be my ultimate goal.  Correct me if I am wrong on that.

Thanks for any input,

Dave

Comment: Is this going to be a desktop application or one with a web front end?

Answer (score 3):

If your goal is to get back into software development, then I recommend that you first ask yourself what type of industry and development setting you'd like to work in. Learn something about the skills those industries are demanding...  Then hit Monster and peruse the job qualifications for companies in those industries. Don't limit your view to just language names and broad job descriptions either, but really try to get an idea what sort of developer they're looking for and whether you'd fit in well.

You will be able to find many interesting technologies in lots of different business domains, but what do you really want to be working to help deliver?  Python coding, for example, may be interesting, but I'm sure you'd be more interested if it were supporting your motorsport interest in some way versus, say, baby food.  When you have the business domains narrowed down, then you can focus on the background required to get jobs in those industries.

You will find an endless set of recommended "hot" techologies if you search for them.  I'm sure you can find a list, or post, which will confirm any bias you have on what to learn.  But chasing the technology of the day may lead to an unfulfilling day-to-day job if what you're applying it to is not something you find interesting.

Answer (score 0):

I would say that the answer depends on what type of job you want to do. The Fortune 500 company I worked at last summer had everything from mainframe c and cobol, java EE, .net to ruby on rails and python in applications. There are still alot of jobs maintaining legacy desktop applications. But the web atmosphere is obviously the future of business computing, and java EE and .NET are huge players in that arena. As for the project you are describing. I've done QT applications with python and there are python libraries for GTK that I've seen used to run apps in Windows. I've also used java swing and awt to build graphical applications and other than the learning curve for the layout system it works really well for building applications. I wrote a really basic windows application using visual studio and C# one time and that seemed to me to be very easy to write.

Answer (score 0):

Enterprise level Java or .NET involve a fairly steep learning curve, so I would have those as a medium-long term goal rather than try and learn that tech immediately.

It seems to me that learning a high productivity web framework is the best way for you to go. "Ruby on Rails" seems to be a hot ticket at the moment. I've only had a small look at it, but it seems pretty quick and straightforward. Your drag racing app would be a good place to start.

Build a couple of websites for yourself using the tech. Then build a couple of websites for friends for a nominal fee. After that, see if you can find a real client (perhaps a local business). If you have 2 or 3 of those under your belt, then a potential employer will at least take notice.

One warning, though - people expect web sites to look *nice*. If you don't have good interface design skills yourself, it will be in your best interest to hire a designer to pretty up whatever you produce.

Answer (score 0):

For a Windows desktop application, you can use C# and the various .NET APIs, and store your data in either a Microsoft-provided database, or SQLite, which is a reliable, server-free SQL implementation. (I don't know anything about Microsoft tech, hence the vagueness of my answer.) There is a lot of work available using C# and .NET, and it should be easy to pick up. You'll meet less resistance on the Windows platform with Microsoft's kit than with third-party languages like Python.